# FxCop not reflecting changes

Tags: c#, fxcop

I am trying to get my head around FxCop.  (Shouldn't be that hard).  I am looking at an existing project so I thought I would start with just one of the small helper libraries.  It is my "common" library that has things like extension methods.

The first time I ran it over the common DLL I got the following error with an extension method, (I pointed it at the debug folder compiled DLL):

```
CriticalWarning, Certainty 75, for IdentifiersShouldBeSpelledCorrectly
{
Target       : #IsNullOrEmptyOrJustSpaces(System.String)  (IntrospectionTargetMember)
Id           : s  (String)
Location     : file:///C:/hoh_code/bailey_dev/Bailey/trunk/source/Bailey.Common/Extensions/StringExtensions.cs<9>  (String)
Resolution   : "In method 'StringExtensions.IsNullOrEmptyOrJustSpaces(
               this string)', consider providing a more meaningful 
               name than parameter name 's'."
Help         : http://msdn2.microsoft.com/library/bb264492(VS.90).aspx  (String)
Category     : Microsoft.Naming  (String)
CheckId      : CA1704  (String)
RuleFile     : Naming Rules  (String)
Info         : "The individual words that make up an identifier should 
               not be abbreviated and should be spelled correctly. 
               If this rule generates a false positive on a term that 
               should be recognized, add the word to the FxCop custom 
               dictionary."
Created      : 04/02/2010 12:58:50  (DateTime)
LastSeen     : 04/02/2010 12:58:50  (DateTime)
Status       : Active  (MessageStatus)
Fix Category : Breaking  (FixCategories)
```

the class used to look like this:

```
using System;

namespace Bailey.Common.Extensions
{
   public static class StringExtensions
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Checks that a string is either, NULL an Empty String or contains only spaces.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="s">The string to be checked</param>
       /// <returns>bool value</returns>
       public static bool IsNullOrEmptyOrJustSpaces(this string s)
       {
           return (s == null || s.Trim() == String.Empty);
       }
   }
}
```

Now it looks like this:

```
using System;

namespace Bailey.Common.Extensions
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// Checks that a string is either, NULL an Empty String or contains only spaces.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="stringToBeChecked">The string to be checked</param>
       /// <returns>bool value</returns>
       public static bool IsNullOrEmptyOrJustSpaces(this string stringToBeChecked)
       {
           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToBeChecked)) { return true; }
           return String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToBeChecked.Trim());
       }
    }
}
```

I have tried rerunning FxCop, deleting the compiled DLL, deleting the whole library and pulling it back out of SVN and rebooting the machine but I still get the same error.

As I understand it (could be wrong), That error should no longer be appearing as I have fixed the poor naming and the comments, build, rebuild and cleaned the project but it still says I am doing it wrong.

My ultimate goal is to have this running via my new CI Server and saving out to a file, but I do not want to go that far till I have the basics working and clean in my mind.

Could someone help me understand where I am going wrong please?

Thanks

**Edit**

I think I must have been pointing to the wrong DLL some how, would swear I checked the path, I know I went to the root of C at least once to retrace the path to check that.  It is now picking up a **load** more errors in the library and is reflecting the changes I make each time.

Comment: Are you sure that FXCop is pointing at the correct target? I have made the mistake of pointing it at a release dll, but had been compiling in debug.

Comment: Hi StingyJack, I think you must be right, edited the post to reflect that.  Must have been doing something stupid.